# Why won't my key frames animation work on my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am currently building a checkers game and im trying to get a working animation code to work on a checker piece so it moves slowly to the next spot.

Here is my css:

```
@keyframes animateCheckerPiece {

            0% {top: 80px}
            50% {top: 270px}
            100% {top: 80px}
        }
.redChecker {

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border: solid red 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is my source code:

```
<tr id="row_C">
                    <td id="C1" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C2" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r9" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                    <td id="C3" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C4" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r10" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                    <td id="C5" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C6" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r11" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                    <td id="C7" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C8" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r12" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                </tr>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var piece, getId;

function chooseMove(event) {

    "use strict";

    getId = event.target.id;

    document.getElementById(getId).style.borderColor = "yellow";

    $("td").addClass("hover");
    $("#msg").html("Choose a spot to move to");

}

function movePiece(event) {

    "use strict";

    var piece = getId;
    var getLocId = event.target.id;

    $(piece).animate({ 
        top: "-=30px",
      }, 2000);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not related javascript. your css codes is wrong.

```js
var piece, getId;

function chooseMove(event) {

    "use strict";

    getId = event.target.id;

    document.getElementById(getId).style.borderColor = "yellow";

    $("td").addClass("hover");
    $("#msg").html("Choose a spot to move to");

}

function movePiece(event) {

    "use strict";

    var piece = getId;
    var getLocId = event.target.id;

    $(piece).animate({ 
        top: "-=30px",
      }, 2000);

}
```

```css
.redChecker {

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border: solid red 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: relative;
  animation: animateCheckerPiece 2s linear;
}

@keyframes animateCheckerPiece {

            0% {top: 80px}
            50% {top: 270px}
            100% {top: 80px}
        }
```

```html
<tr id="row_C">
                    <td id="C1" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C2" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r9" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                    <td id="C3" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C4" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r10" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                    <td id="C5" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C6" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r11" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                    <td id="C7" class="odd"></td>
                    <td id="C8" class="even"><div align="center"><div id="r12" class="redChecker" onClick="chooseMove(event);"></div></div></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif it seems like you were not using your keyframes in CSS `animation: animateCheckerPiece 2s linear;`

Comment: @YashKaranke it's not *me*, I am a simple user that read *the CSS is wrong* and don't want to spend 10min finding the difference between both code to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason is you don't call the animation in your style,

here your styling after edit

```
.redChecker {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid red 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  animation: animateCheckerPiece 3.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

there is another options you can add in one line

```
animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode;
```

also, check MDN and how it works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation